# Django model self._meta.get_all_field_names() is returning a field that is not in my model?

Tags: python, django, debugging

for some reason, when I run `self._meta.get_all_field_names()`, I get this output:

```
['account_created', 'email', 'first_name', u'id', 'last_active',
 'last_name', 'password', 'song', 'username']
```

As you can see, there is no "song" field inside my class (but I do have another model named "song"). Could this be a bug or am I doing something wrong?

```
class user(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    account_created = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
    last_active = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        # return "{} {} {} {} {} {} {}".format(self.first_name,self.last_name,self.username, self.password,self.email, self.account_created,self.last_active)
        return ",".join(["{}:{} ".format(i,getattr(self,i)) for i in self._meta.get_all_field_names() if i != "song"])
```

Here is my "song" class if it is of any help:

```
class song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(user,null=True,blank=True)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    filesize = models.BigIntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{} by {}".format(self.title,self.artist)
```

Comment: Seems to me that the foreign key to `user` (the `submitted_by` field) creates that.

Comment: Please :'( https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names

Comment: I just started learning Django a few days ago, give me a break :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `song` class has a foreign key `submitted_by` which points to `user`, so there is a [reverse relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) from `user` to `song`.

In Django 1.7 and earlier you could try using `self._meta.local_fields`:

```
[x.name for x in self._meta.local_fields]
```

That will ignore many to many fields (you don't have any on the `user` model), which you can get with:

```
[x.name for x in self._meta.local_many_to_many]
```

In the upcoming Django 1.8, the [`Model._meta`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/meta/) API has been formalized, so it should be more straight forward to introspect models like this.